Fuel Rich combustion
Question
A fuel rich mixture of certain Hydro-Carbon fuel C12H24 and oxygen (O2) at standard condition, is burnt at a mixture ratio 2.5. Assuming initially all the H is oxidized to H2O and thereafter Carbon is oxidized, how do I work out the balanced formula for this combustion ?
What I've tried so far
Molar Mass of C12H24 = 168 g/mol
Molar Mass of O2     = 32  g/mol
Yielding the molar ratios
$$\frac{1 g}{168 g/mol}:\frac{2.5g}{32 g/mol}$$
Multiplying both sides by 168
$$168 \frac{1 g}{168 g/mol}: 168 \frac{2.5g}{32 g/mol}$$
$$1:13.125$$
$$8:105$$
Resulted in:
$$8\ C_{12}H_{24} + 105\ O_2 => 96 \ H_2O + 9\ CO + 87\ C$$
But this is not what's given as the answer. The text Claims, some CO2 being generated by further oxidizing CO as well. My understanding is this could only happen when all the carbon getting first oxidized into CO.
If someone could shed some light to get the correctly balanced formula, its much appreciated.
Thanks

it would be helpful if the answer that you found in the text is mentioned clearly.

Chem+Math MathJax formatting:
Basics / Expressions/formulas/equations / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Balancing the equation is matter of ability to manipulate with small natural numbers. // $$ \ce{8 C12H24 + 105 O2 -> 96 H2O + 96 C + 114 O  } \
\implies  \ce{8 C12H24 + 105 O2 -> 96 H2O + 96 CO + 18 O  } \
\implies  \ce{8 C12H24 + 105 O2 -> 96 H2O + 78 CO + 18 CO2}$$

You missed $\ce{105 O2}$ means  $\ce{210 O}$

What is the meaning of this number $2.5$ ? Is it the ratio of the masses $\ce{O2}$ and of alcane ? Or is it the ratio of the amount in mole of $\ce{O2}$  and mole of alcane ? Or the inverse ratio of the amounts  of alcanes compared to amount of $\ce{O2}$ ?

bro i guess he is saying 2 is to 5 ratio

Thanks @Pautnik for pointing out the silly mistake from my end.

Thanks @Maurice and Anjankumar Mass ratio is the ratio of masses of oxidizer and fuel

Poutnik gave very creative way to balance asking combustion reaction. An another way to balance this reaction is using mathematical equations. Data given is as follows:

fuel to oxygen mass ratio: $\pu{1 g}$ fuel $(\ce{C12H24})$ with $\pu{2.5 g}$ oxygen $(\ce{O2})$
all the $\ce{H}$ in fuel is oxidized to $\ce{H2O}$
if the mixture have enough $\ce{O2}$ remained, all $\ce{C}$ in fuel is oxidized to $\ce{CO/CO2}$

From first bullet you can calculate the mol ratio of fuel to oxygen:
$$\text{mol ratio used } (\ce{C12H24}:\ce{O2}) = \frac{\pu{1 g}}{\pu{168 g mol-1}}:\frac{\pu{2.5 g}}{\pu{32 g mol-1}} =8:105 $$
Now we can write the chemical equation using calculated mol ratio and the fact in second bullet as follows:
$$\ce{8 C12H24 + 105 O2 -> 96 H2O + xCO + yCO2}$$
The unknown two integer $(x,y)$ we can calculated by setting up two equations simply balancing carbon and oxygen in chemical equation. Balancing carbon mols gives the equation $(1)$:
$$ x + y = 96 \tag1$$
Balancing oxygen mols gives the equation $(2)$:
$$ x + 2y = 2 \times 105 - 96 = 114 \tag2$$
Subtracting the equation $(1)$ from $(2)$ gives the integer $y$:
$$(2) - (1): \ y = 114 - 96 = 18 $$
Now, from equation $(1)$ you can find the other integer $x$:
$$x = 96 - y = 96 - 18 = 78$$
Thus, balanced combustion equation under given condition is:
$$\ce{8 C12H24 + 105 O2 -> 96 H2O + 78 CO + 18 CO2}$$

Initial combustion reaction:
C12H24 + O2 → CO2 + CO + C + H2O
Given mixture ratio:
The mixture ratio is 2.5, indicating a fuel-rich mixture.
Stoichiometric oxygen required for complete combustion:
C12H24 + 18O2 → 12CO2 + 12H2O
Adjust for fuel-rich conditions:
Given the mixture ratio of 2.5, the actual oxygen used is,
Actual O2 =  18/2.5 = 7.2 moles of O2
Balance the equation with adjusted oxygen:
Let's multiply by 8 for simplicity,
8C12H24 + 8*7.2O2
Therefore, the adjusted reaction is:
8C12H24 + 57.6O2
Balance the reaction for incomplete combustion:
Assume initially all hydrogen is oxidized to water, and then carbon is partially oxidized to CO and CO2.
Balancing the Reaction:
Balancing Hydrogen:
Each C12H24 has 24 hydrogen atoms, forming 12 H2O:
8C12H24 + aO2 → bCO2 + cCO + dC + 96H2O
Determine total moles of oxygen:
Each H2O requires 1 O atom.
96 H2O requires 96 O atoms.
Total oxygen atoms available from 105 moles of O2:
105 * 2 = 210 O atoms
Remaining oxygen atoms after forming H2O:
210 - 96 = 114 O atoms
These remaining 114 O atoms are used for forming CO2 and CO:
Balancing Carbon considering all initially forms CO and part to CO2:
8C12H24 provides 96 C atoms.
Let:
x moles of CO2
y moles of CO
z mol.
